# Open Files Created with BSAVE in QuickBasic?

Tags: basic, qbasic, quickbasic

I have some files that were created using BSAVE in QuickBasic. I'm wondering how I can load/view these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received assistance over at the FreeBasic forums. Its easy to do if you download and install the FreeBasic compiler / IDE. Here is the relevant thread:
http://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12554&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0
Essentially, it loads the image using BLOAD like one normally would and then BSAVEs it as a BMP. I suppose it would be pretty easy to create an app. that did this by just prompting for source and output files...

Answer (score 2):

I would try installing pcpaint (free) http://www.shdon.com/software/pcpaint
Change the extension to .PIC and try to open it. Apparently this program used bsave to save images with the extention .pic.
Hope this works!